# Problems with a vector of std::threads in C++11 counting bigrams of letters and words

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdvector, stdthread

I am trying to implement a concurrent program to count occurrences of bigrams of words and letters in text files. The core are the two functions that calculate the bigrams. In the `main` I start threads with one of the two functions. There is a main `for` that starts threads and pushes them in a `vector`.

```
std::vector<std::thread *> threads;
std::pair<std::string, int> current_job;


for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    current_job = filenames.front();// ex. <baskerville.txt, 1>
    filenames.pop();
    if (current_job.second == 0) {
        threads.push_back(new std::thread(sentence_bigrams_letters, std::cref(current_job.first), std::ref(v),
                                          std::ref(lock_chars)));
    } else if (current_job.second == 1) {
        threads.push_back(
                new std::thread(sentence_bigrams, std::cref(current_job.first), std::ref(m), std::ref(lock_words)));
    }

} 

for (unsigned int k = 0; k < threads.size(); k++) {
        threads.at(k)->join();
        delete (threads.at(k));
    }
```

There are two text files called *baskerville.txt* and *dorian.txt* so `filenames` has a total of 4 elements. The program runs but the output that prints the threads make no sense. Each thread prints the count of a particular bigram with the bigram itself, the name of file he is reading and his id. This is the output:

```
199 y,t .\Text\dorian.txt 4 /letters
398 y,t .\Text\dorian.txt 2 /letters
33 a, few .\Text\dorian.txt 3 /words
66 a, few .\Text\dorian.txt 5 /words
```

It doesn't make any sense to me so if someone has a clue about what is going on it would be really helpful.

Comment: how big is the program? could you post all of it?

Comment: the program is not so big and the other parts of the code work because the program works in the sequential version so i think the error is not there

Comment: You tagged this C++11... why don't you use more C++11? Like `for(auto &thread: threads) { thread->join(); delete thread; }`. Also, you could make the vector hold the thread objects themselves instead of just the pointers, use `threads.emplace_back(stentence_bigrams_letters, ...);`

Comment: @G.Sliepen: And using the `vector` of actual thread objects, rather than pointers, also means you don't need to worry about manual memory management; you need to `join`, but you can't forget (or accidentally bypass) memory release. Using `std::move` for stuff you'll throw away anyway would also save some cycles/memory churn.

Comment: @ShadowRanger So I don't need to delete the threads afterwards if I use an array of actual threads?

Comment: @GianmarcoBiscini: Well, I'd recommend a `vector`, but yeah, when you didn't call `new`, you don't call `delete` (barring weird APIs that do the `new` for you, but those aren't part of the standard lib).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
The problem was that i am passing the string current_job.first as a reference, and the reference was being changed in the for loop iterations.
So instead of:

```
threads.push_back(new std::thread(sentence_bigrams_letters, std::cref(current_job.first), std::ref(v),
                                      std::ref(lock_chars)));
```

it is:

```
threads.push_back(new std::thread(sentence_bigrams_letters, current_job.first, std::ref(v),
                                          std::ref(lock_chars)));
```

and now it works